# Nuxtjs 3 - i18n - mixing multipleDomains and prefix_except_default strategy

Tags: internationalization, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vue-i18n

We're building a Nuxt 3 app with i18n and SSR, and we need to support different URL structures for different locales. Specifically, for some locales, we need to have a separate domain, while for others, we need to use prefixes.

For example:

- American English: example.com/en-us
- German: example.com/de-de
- Australia: example.com.au (note there's no prefix)

We tried enabling the **`multipleDomains = true`** option in the Nuxt config, but it resulted in the whole app defaulting to the no_prefix strategy, which doesn't meet our requirements.

We're currently exploring an option of combining a dynamic root folder **`pages/_locale`** with middleware that will programmatically set the i18n locale based on the route. However, we're not sure if this is the best approach.

What other approaches can you recommend? And how can we ensure that the homepage always redirects to the detected locale or fallback value of en-us?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: were you able to fix it? I am having same issue :)